# Python - Create a dictionary out of a nested lists

Tags: python, nested, directory

I am currently working on a task, where I should make trading decisions on the base of MA Crossovers.

I am thinking about an approach which involves a dictionary, however, I am still really inexperienced in how to create those.

My idea is to convert a list like following:

```
cross = [[2, 2], [3, 1], [6, 2], [9, 1], [12, 1]]
```

where: [time_index, buy_index]

such that, it leaves me with a directory like

```
{'0': 0, '1':0, '2':2, ... , '12':1 }
```

The values 0, 1, 2 are standing for: do nothing, buy and sell respectively.

Any help, idea or source to gather knowledge from is super appreciated!

Comment: This isn't really an SO question, and it's "dictionary" rather than "directory". Is there some specific thing you need help with?

Comment: maybe you need `dict(cross)` => done

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `f-string` to bring in those quotes to your `key`

```
cross = [[2, 2], [3, 1], [6, 2], [9, 1], [12, 1]] 

new_dict = {}
new_dict['0'] = 0
new_dict['1'] = 1

for i in cross:
    new_dict[f'"{i[0]}"'] = i[1] 

print(new_dict)
```

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python/stack_overflow$ python3.7 nest_dict.py 
> {'0': 0, '1': 1, '"2"': 2, '"3"': 1, '"6"': 2, '"9"': 1, '"12"': 1}
> ```